# PHPでcurlを使って、Web APIへPOST送信できない

Tags: php, api, php-curl

下記のコードを実行しても、chatworkにメッセージが飛ばせません。
オプションの設定にvar_dumpをつけましたが、全てtrueなので原因がわかりませんでした。

原因について、アドバイスを頂いてもよろしいでしょうか。

```php
//***チャットボット作成：[mikanのDBにメンバーが登録されたら、chatworkの自分の板にmsgを送信]
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset = utf-8"); //レスポンスのブラウザ表示の時に、文字化けを防ぐため
    $header = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','X-ChatWorkToken: 自分のAPIトークン');
    $url = "https://www.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/{room_id}/messages"; //自分の部屋のroom_id
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $body = array(
      'body' => 'APIの連携完了',
      'self_unread' => '0'
    );
    $body_data = $data = http_build_query($body, "", "&");

    //[TODO] HTTPリクエストヘッダ情報の設定
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //エラー時にステータスコードを表示したいため文字列へ

    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

    $result = json_decode($response);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
      echo 'Curl error'.curl_error($ch);
      $err_msg[] = 'chatwork連携失敗しました'; //こちらの変数は、載せているコードとは他の場所で定義しています。
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    //*****チャットボット作成ここまで*****
```

Answer (score 1):

#### チャットワークAPIへのURLが間違っていました！

```
https://www.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/{room_id}/messages
```

上記のURLのroom_idのかっこ{}を外して

```
https://www.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/room_id/messages
```

と、記述を修正したら、リクエストが通りました！